# Duration of migration to HRD?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was just testing the process of migration of data from M/S to HRD,
i.e., x.appspot.com to x-hrd.appspot.com, but it took more than 2 days to complete the migration !!

I just want to ask some questions after experiencing the migration process,

- How long will it takes to migrate the 5GB of data from M/S to HRD ?
- What happens to my M/S app when the migration is in progress( if it is extending to more than 2days ) ?
- What if the migration hangs in between ? how do i go back to my M/S state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It took my 3 GB of data about 30 minutes to transfer. I don't think Google offer any particular time guarantee about this.
2. Your M/S app will be fine. Your users will not be affected by the transition in progress.
3. You don't switch to HRD until the migration is totally done. If it hangs, just don't switch. You won't have to "go back."